# How to display Form Components from List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

this question might be really stupid but here it is anyway. What I want my programm to do: When I press a button I want to add a DatePicker Component to a List and then display all the Components in the Main Form. However when I press the button it only adds the components but doesnt show them in the Form Window. No Errors are thrown. What do I have to do to display the DatePicker Components in the Main Form?

```
//class containing the List of Components
     class Eintrag
        {
            static public List<DateTimePicker> Anfangszeit = new List<DateTimePicker>();
        }

//Main Form Class
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Eintrag.Anfangszeit.Add(new DateTimePicker());
                for (int i = 0; i < Eintrag.Anfangszeit.Count; i++)
                {
                    Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 50 + 50*i);
                    Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);
                    Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Visible = true;
                    Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Form.Controls.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.controlcollection.add?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. Also the site says: "adds a TextBox and Label control to the control collection of a form" so thats probably the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Wu is right, you have to add the Controls to the Form via `Controls.Add()`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Eintrag.Anfangszeit.Add(new DateTimePicker());
    for (int i = 0; i < Eintrag.Anfangszeit.Count; i++) {
        Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 50 + 50 * i);
        Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);
        Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i]);
        Eintrag.Anfangszeit[i].Show();            
    }
}
```